# How to upload to redis a python's dict of dicts ? (dataframe --> redis)

Tags: python, pandas, redis, hash-of-hashes

I have to upload on redis a pandas's dataframe with a column as unique key(timestamp).
To do this, I've created a dict in python like this:

```
dict0 = {1431036000: {'col1': '08-05-2015',   'col2': 1.934,  'col3': 905.0} ,
        1431122400: {'col1': '09-05-2015',   'col2': 2.004,  'col3': 700.0}, ..........}
```

and I started a redis client with this

```
db0 = redis.Redis(host = xxxx, port = 6379, db=0)
```

1. What function should I use to upload *dict0* to *db0*, so I can get all values(with labels) by making a get(timestamp)?
2. Having another dict (*dict1*) that I want to upload to another database, is it correct to do this to have the two databases separated ? Cause dict0 and dict1 may have same keys.

> db1 = redis.Redis(host = xxxx, port = 6379, db=1)

If you have suggestions for doing it (dataframe->redis) better let me know,
thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to consider using one of Redis modules like https://redisearch.io or https://redisjson.io